# How to process fast 10,000 small objects stored in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

**The problem**: Given a list of 10000 paths to objects stored in S3, I need to process the corresponding objects fast (under 1 second). Each object is 40 KB.

**The background**: Each object represents a document. Each document is associated with one or more users (could be a thousand users or more, hence duplication of documents is avoided). We need to process all documents associated with a given user. The processing is a search in the documents' contents based on a given query. The exact details of the search are unimportant here, except for the fact that the search results are small (~1KB). In the above problem statement, the user has 10000 documents associated with him.

An approach I have already tested is to use parallelization by utilizing multiple instances of a Lambda function, each downloading and processing a part of the list of objects.

The computation part of this approach is fast. It is the downloading of objects that is the bottleneck. I would like to find a smarter (cheaper and more performant) approach.

One idea is to merge all 10,000 objects into a single temporary object and then download the latter large object with a single `get` request. However, the only way of doing this that I am aware of is by multipart upload, which [requires that each part be at least 5 MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html). In my case, the parts are 40 KB each. I cannot merge the parts in advance, since an object can be associated with many different users and thus appear in combination with different objects.

Is there a workaround or a different approach I can use?

P.S. The question [at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUCbTOwBxKSjmaTSY7ul52zQ/how-to-process-fast-10-000-small-objects-stored-in-s3)

Comment: I'm [still](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77430114/51685) pretty sure S3 isn't the right storage for this if you need this sort of performance for a bunch of small items. It's not "cloud native", but I think you're going to need a regular ol' EC2 instance with fast local NVMe storage and some code there.

Comment: @AKX What do you mean by S3 not being cloud-native? What's `ol' EC2` (I guess it's a typo, but can't figure out what you meant)? EC2 sounds like headache. I will have to run a server (Django?) to accept requests; or is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I meant using EC2 instead of lambdas and so on isn't "cloud-native", not that S3 isn't. And the phrase was ["regular ol' (old) EC2"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248355/whats-the-origin-etymology-of-the-phrase-regular-old-does-it-have-a-clearly).

Comment: Pre-index the documents into Elasticsearch (or OpenSearch serverless if it suits your query latency requirements).

Comment: @jarmod Their instances are very expensive... This approach is much more expensive than my current approach.

Comment: I think you can only choose two from "cheap, fast, easy" here...

Comment: Lightweight solution such as https://github.com/valeriansaliou/sonic?

Comment: @jarmod Based on OP's earlier comments (in their questions before), the "documents" are actually binary vectors of some sort already, if I understood correctly. I recommended e.g. https://github.com/apache/kvrocks.

Comment: @AKX Your understanding is correct. "I think you can only choose two from 'cheap, fast, easy' here..." I love this formulation. But a solution based on EC2 with super-fast disks and some kind of distributed database seems to only hit the "fast" target. I already hit (well, pending concurrency quota increase) this target with S3+Lambda approach, but at the cost of 300 GB-sec of AWS Lambda per search request.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html? If you're looking to maximize performance on S3 with lots of files, you need to split your data between multiple prefixes.

Comment: Also, Python might not be the best language choice. Or perhaps you should use the `multiprocessing` library rather than the `threading` library. Or maybe you need to combine your files at load time, rather than at runtime. There are lots of options, and this question seems far too broad, especially since you're focused on a particular implementation rather than the underlying problem.

Comment: @kdgregory Yes, I am using prefixes. However, this does not change the cost, which is what I am trying to improve. The question asks for a different approach as well. What do you mean by combining files at load time, given that I don't know which files go together until the user submits the search query? How would another language help when the bottleneck probably has to do with the number of connections a Lambda instance can handle in parallel?

Comment: You mentioned that the "exact details of the search are unimportant here" so I don't know what you're actually doing here or how arbitrary you need the search to be but did you consider modeling/indexing the data in some way to make it query-efficient in DynamoDB?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, DynamoDB is much faster. Unfortunately, they have a pricing scheme that makes my scenario very expensive. Namely, reading each item of 40KB, even with eventually correct reads, is 5 RCU. With 10,000 items, we arrive at 50,000 RCU for a single search request.

Comment: @jarmod As for details of the search, each one of 10,000 objects is basically 100 dense embedding vectors with 384 dimensions. The search is done by computing the dot product of each of the 1,000,000 vectors with the query vector and selecting 100 vectors with the smallest dot product. In shorter terms, it is an exact KNN search among 1,000,000 vectors with K=100.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Have you considered/looked at a vector database like Qdrant for this? (Not affiliated with Qdrant, have just played around with it and it's been good.)

Comment: @AKX Sure. I looked at both Qdrant and Pinecone and `pgvector`. One huge challenge with approximate NN search (which is what these tools are good at) is being able use filtering. `pgvector` does not solve that. The others charge based on keeping all the vectors and huge indexes in RAM, which comes out to astronomical amounts.

Comment: Pretty sure qdrant doesn't charge you for anything if you just run their Docker image.

Comment: @AKX Right, I was talking about their cloud solution. But you would have to run an instance (e.g. EC2) that has enough RAM, which is darn expensive. That's in addition to the need to manage it.

Comment: Qdrant supports memory-mapped (i.e. disk-backed) storage for vectors too, so you don't necessarily need lots of RAM.

Comment: Re combining the files: reading a small number of large files from S3 is far more efficient than reading a large number of small files. Based on your comments, it appears that you have 1,000,000 independent data objects. Are they split into 10,000 files for a reason, or is that just how you thought would be best to process? I would instead try loading the entire 400 MB into memory and then _perhaps_ do a parallel in-memory search (being aware of the limitations of the Python GIL). You _may_ get better performance from loading some _small_ number of component files.

Comment: If this Lambda will be called relatively frequently, then loading the data outside of the Lambda handler will mean that you can cache it between requests and not be constantly reading from S3. You may need provisioned concurrency on the Lambda to meet your performance targets. And you may find that it's more cost-effective to run an always-on service. Only you can decide this.

Comment: And re general performance, I think you've been making a number of unfounded assumptions and trying to "solve" them. In a comment on another one of your questions I suggested that you exercise your implementations locally, to take Lambda out of the picture. And if you have similar performance issues doing that, then you'll have more ability to debug them.

Comment: @kdgregory I implemented multiprocessing using [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/) tutorial. Not sure why, but it is terribly slow.

Comment: @AKX Yes, that saves a lot (they claim 70% of RAM), but would still be quite expensive. In addition, they assume a single category for each vector. In my case, each vector can be associated with a thousand of categories (users in my case). Even if I can filter on a condition like `query_user_id in vector.list_of_user_ids`, the index to support such a query would be huge, as it has to contain edges in the HNSW graph for all the users. In addition, I cannot imagine updating a vector not being a very timely operation which also necessitates re-indexing to keep the nice properties of the graph.

Comment: @kdgregory It is not random. Each object corresponds to a document (see the background in the question). Putting all of 400 MB in memory is what my current approach is doing, but it has to bring those 400 MB from memory, which involves 10,000 get requests to S3. I hope that this Lambda will be called frequently :) Nonetheless, if the calls are by different users, then different sets of documents will need to be loaded and caching in memory will probably not be very effective in this case. As for provisioned concurrency, I hope to get to the point when it pays.

Comment: @kdgregory How would you go about debugging diminishing returns of adding more threads locally?

Comment: @AKX I tried it with EC2 instance `c6id.xlarge`, gp3, 16,000 IOPS. Sequentially reading 10,000 binary files of ~40 KB each took about 250ms. Wow. Now, the volume's throughput was set at 125 MBps, so I have no clue how it could read 400MB in anything less than 3 seconds. With 1000 MBps, it strangely did not become much faster and took 240ms... This performance comes with the price tag of $250/month, but I can begin with something more modest. The big stopper for me is that, given that I am starting this business all on my own, I am afraid of the overhead of managing a production instance...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Glad you gave EC2 a shot. I'd guess the page cache is to blame for the seemingly-too-fast read speeds, but that's what it's supposed to do. (You can [`drop_caches`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17936/setting-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-to-clear-cache) to benchmark with a cold cache.) For what it's worth, I spun up a $25/mo instance (on Google) and it takes about 1.15 seconds to read + md5 hash 10,000 random 40k files out of 50,000 with a hot cache, and 8.6 seconds with a dropped cache.

Comment: @AKX When there are 1M files and 10K randomly chosen files are needed each time, cache won't help much, will it? I still have a feeling that S3 will win, as even a weaker instance with the cheapest hard disk should be able to submit thousands of `get` requests to S3 in parallel...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I wouldn't necessarily bet on that being the case, unless you actively go for a spinning-rust hard disk. Also, you could mix these for a best-of-both-world approach: cache that data onto the instance, get it from there if it is available, and get it from S3 if it isn't...

Comment: @AKX I am not sure I understand what you mean regarding the HDD: submitting thousands of `get` requests to S3 in parallel has nothing to do with the disk at all, does it? As for caching, the whole idea of caching as I understand it relies on some data being requested much more often than other. If all users are equally likely to submit a search request, then this assumption does not hold.

Comment: I meant "I'm not sure getting things from S3 will win, unless the other contestant in this race is a spinning-rust HDD". Also, the assumption that your searches are random is still just an assumption, and I don't think it's necessarily a good one.

Comment: @AKX There seems to be something fundamental that I am missing and you are aware of. Given that the network bandwidth is easily greater than the throughput of even the fastest disk volume, why shouldn't I expect that, with sufficient parallelization (which should be possible with an I/O-bound load like this), reading from S3 will be faster than reading from even the fastest disk volume?

Comment: Throughput could be greater _if_ you can saturate the connection, but that will not happen with tons of tiny requests due to various overheads. If you have a large file, you _might_ be able to saturate it, but likely not with a single request either (you'd likely need multiple `Range` requests). (I recall telling you you'd have a bad time with S3 and tiny files.)

Comment: @AKX I would like to understand what these overheads are. Are they related to GIL? I asked a focused question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77480325/2725810

Comment: Mostly not GIL, but request signing, TCP, TLS, HTTP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can store objects up to 400KB in DynamoDB.
Searching should be much faster.
You just need to think what attribute use as a partition key, and which attributes you need to search by and put them into item key or secondary index.

Comment: Yes, DynamoDB is much faster. Unfortunately, they have a pricing scheme that makes my scenario very expensive. Namely, reading each item of 40KB, even with eventually correct reads, is 5 RCU. With 10,000 items, we arrive at 50,000 RCU for a single search request.